# Confirm alert when leaving page if form is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I need help. I want to display confirm alert if user leave page and if form is filled or at least some of the fields on form are filled. I have following code that is functioning in Chrome but not working in Firefox. Also the alert is displayed even when the form fields are empty.

Following is my code,

```
 $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
            return ''; //Are you sure you want to leave?';
        });
```

So I need help so I can produce alert in Firefox, and all other browsers when form is completely or partially filled but not produce any alert when form is empty. I tried making use of viewstate. Checking if viewstate value is different then produce alert, but it's not working as I expected

another piece of code I tried is

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var message = "Your confirmation message goes here.",
  e = e || window.event;
  // For IE and Firefox
  if (e) {
  e.returnValue = message;
  }

    // For Safari
  return message;
```

};

But the above code does not check if form  is filled or not. I want alert when form is partially or completely filled

Comment: @ketan I added some more code

Answer (score 0):

I didnt test this but here is a quick shot at it:

```
 $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
      $('input').each(function () {
        if(this.value.length > 0){
        alert('you entered data');
        return false;
      }
   });

});
```

Comment: This isn't working. But the code looks fine but not sure why it's not working

Comment: Sounds like a connection issue, not a JS error. Its working fine for me

Comment: Also, rather than an alert, I'd use a confirm dialogue so the user can cancel

Comment: So you went to the fiddle added characters to the fields, clicked the button and didnt get an alert? If thats true Im not sure what else to do for you sir.

Comment: actually I want it on beforeunload, it's working on click but it's not working on beforeunload event

Comment: Alright well I didnt test it on that but the logic I gave you will work if you find the correct event handler for the unload. There is a deprecated method in jquery but other than that Im not sure

Comment: Try window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function( event ) { });

Comment: actually what I figured out that inside beforeunload event you can't code. The code wont execute

Answer (score 0):

This should work, just give a try.It will take care of empty spaces also.

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
 if(!$.trim(this.value).length) {
           alert('Fill Data')
     }
});
```